What is the portable way to cast to-and-from a `char`, preserving the same bit pattern?
Many methods take char to be the 'byte type' 1. However, it is unclear (to me) whether it is implementation defined behaviour what a cast from an unsigned char to a char ought to do when the unsigned char's value is greater than CHAR_MAX.
This section is from C++11 (ISO/IEC 14882:2011) §4.7 Integral conversions [conv.integral/2]:

If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and bit-field width); otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.

This section of the standard is also mentioned in a similar question, but no mention is given to how we can preserve the bit-pattern for these conversions.
So, how should I cast a uint8_t, unsigned char, or other char-width type to-and-from a char, preserving the bit pattern?
Note: This question is about C++ in general, not a specific version. If something was unacceptable in C++11, but works in C++14, then it would be useful if the answer could contrast the two versions.
1: for example, x64 SIMD intrinsics such as __m128i _mm_set1_epi8(char) use char.

Casting between signed and unsigned types of the same size does not change the bit pattern thanks to 2's compliment.

The quote you are talking about is for conversions, i.e, signed char foo = unsigned_vchar_vat  Doing conat char * data = &unsigned_variable lets you inspect the bytes of unsigned_variable.

@Jason If you can quote that this is guaranteed portably by the standard, you can post this as an answer.

@NathanOliver If you believe this is the recommended (and specified) way to convert maintaining the bit pattern, (i.e. *(unsigned char *)&ch or something similar), this is an answer.

I don't think it's in the standard because C++ is supposed to be able to run on machines that do not have 2's compliment processors.  You aren't going to find many of those anymore and worrying about them is super pedantic.

@Jason you're not even guaranteed how many bits are in the char type.  Worrying about oddball architectures can seem pedantic, up until the moment you're forced to do it for your job.

@MarkRansom you are guaranteed that char and unsigned char have the same number of bits. The standard doesn't spell it out, but even on non-2's complement machines, the casts here don't change the bits, unless the implementation is being deliberately obtuse.

@Jason That was changed in C++20.  All integer types are required to be two's compliment now.

@MarkRansom If you are generalizing for processors that aren't 8 bit chars, that's absurdly pedantic.  I work in the embedded world, and I've seen more weird architectures than most.  I've never seen a processor that wasn't 8 bit chars and 2s complement.

From C++20, you can use std::bit_cast. This guarantees that you get a bit-for-bit identical value for types with no padding bits, which char and unsigned char are.
Prior to that, you will have to investigate the documentation of each implementation that you intend to use. The implementations1 I am aware of all choose to not modify the bit patterns to arrive at their implementation-defined values.
The wording in the standard is there because the bit patterns that correspond to negative numbers represent different numbers under two's complement, one's complement and sign and magnitude.
Failing that, you can std::memcpy an lvalue unsigned char into an lvalue char

Even when the platform isn't two's complement, it doesn't make sense to change the bit pattern when casting signed <-> unsigned. You might end up with -0, and you end up with a different value to what a two's complement machine would give, but unless the implementation is going out of it's way to be obtuse, it will have the same bit pattern.


Is there no clear way of bit-casting an unsigned char to a char prior to C++20?

@doliphin there's always memcpy

@Caleth that's worthy of another answer.

@MarkRansom I've gone into more detail.

The reason memcpy works is because it doesn't even assume it's copying a char type, it takes void* parameters.  It's as pure a memory copy as C/C++ allows.

std::bit_cast is a tombstone for memcpy. All use cases of memcpy are covered by safe & efficient std functions since C++20. memcpy has lots of caveats and pitfalls, making using code error-prone. The only remaining use case prior to C++20 was type punning (as in OP). memcpy invocations must be generated by compiler or std library implementation. User C++ code containing direct calls to this function raises red flags. Prefer std::bit_cast, if you can switch to C++20 or above.
